# warning on xypic

Tags: warnings, xy-pic

I get several warning about `xypic`, I have no idea what to do about them. Can anyone help me? I can provide more info, if you ask me.
The warnings I get are as follows:

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the warnings and the code producing them it's difficult to say something.

Comment: sorry, i was editing, hope it works now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct call is

```
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
```

and not

```
\usepackage{xypic}
```

The latter line calls a file present only for backward compatibility. The `all` option I suggest is recommended so that you don't have to bother about what extensions you have to load. With `cmtip` the arrow tips are similar to the default one in `\rightarrow`.

The warnings about `\stop` and `\framed` can be ignored, as well as the one from `epstopdf`. Finally, you have a `pdftex` option in `\documentclass`: remove it; if you were told to add it by some guide, throw the guide away. `;-)`

Comment: @Ginger: If the answer worked for you, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark.